# how can i check my quantity before save into database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

how can i check my  `v_total_quantity.total_quantity_box <  $request->input('quantity_box')[$i];`

when i submit data  here is my table and my controller

```
    id_w | id_p  | product_name| total_quantity_box
    10   | 1     | snack       |10
    10   | 2     | watebottle  |10   
    10   | 3     | headphone   |10


  for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $warehouse_products_sell = New Warehouse_products_sell;
        $warehouse_products_sell->id_w = $request->input('idw');
        $warehouse_products_sell->id_c = $request->get('id_c')[$i];
        $warehouse_products_sell->id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];
        $warehouse_products_sell->quantity_box = $request->input('quantity_box')[$i];
        $warehouse_products_sell->price = $request->input('price')[$i];
        $warehouse_products_sell->serial_num = $a;
        $a = DB::table('v_total_quantity')
                ->select([
                'v_total_quantity.id_w',
                'v_total_quantity.id_p',
                'v_total_quantity.total_quantity_box',
                'products.product_name',
                'products.product_unit',
                'products.id_product',
             ])
            ->leftjoin('products', 'v_total_quantity.id_p', '=', 'products.id_p')
            ->where([
                ['v_total_quantity.id_w', '=', $request->input('idw')],
                ['v_total_quantity.id_p', '=', $request->input('quantity_box')],
                ]);

        // if ($a->id_p < $request->input('quantity_box')) {
        //     echo "success";
        // }else{
        //     echo "error";
        // }
        // $warehouse_products_sell->save();
    }
```

but it's not working

in my blade_temp i used dynamic add that's why ive to [$i]

```
 <select style="width:48%;" class="productname" name="id_p[]">
  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> Product Name</option>
 </select>
```

i want to make sure that my total_quantity_box not  -

Comment: `it's not working` is not an error message, and does not tell people trying to help you anything about your problem.  Also, it looks like your question got cut off, the last sentence seems incomplete.

Comment: @Don'tPanic im sorry here i manage my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502971/how-can-i-check-stock-qty-before-add , so sorry im not good in english