# how can loop all data then save it after check all data in loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Now query is already work  but  if I add multiple id_p it's checking only first loop any idea how to fix this I want to check all id_p  $available > 1 then save(); into database

```
$count = count($request->get('quantity_box'));


for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

     $available = $this->check_stock($id_w, $id_p, $qty);
     $id_w = $request->input('idw');
     $id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];

        if($available > 0){
             echo 'success';
        }else{
            echo 'error';
        }
}

private function check_stock($idw, $id_p,$qty){

        $count = DB::table('v_total_quantity')
            ->select([
            'total_quantity_box',
         ])
        ->where('v_total_quantity.id_w',$idw)
        ->where('v_total_quantity.id_p',$id_p)
        ->where('v_total_quantity.total_quantity_box','>',$qty)
        ->count();

        return $count;
    }
```

the error said: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to int

here is my data in v_total_quantiy table

```
    id_w | id_p  | product_name| total_quantity_box
    10   | 1     | snack       |10
    10   | 2     | watebottle  |10   
    10   | 3     | headphone   |10
```

Comment: First change `if($available > '0'){` to `if($available > 0){`  and simply add `->get()` like this `->where('v_total_quantity.id_p',$id_p)->get(); ;)`

Comment: ok ill try it thanks sir @Maraboc

Comment: still not working , Oops i forget my code are in foreach loop sec i'll update my question @Maraboc

Comment: i alrdy updated my question sir @Maraboc

Comment: try to replace `->get()` by `->count()` !!

Comment: is it working ??

Comment: ill updating in my question sec , it' seems work im not sure this is good idea or not

Comment: @maraboc sir i updated i used count() and i try to add qty in my query not sure is this able to use ? sorry here is my first project i nv have experience  before

Comment: @Maraboc query is work but  if i add multiple id_p its checking only first loop any idea how to fix this i want to check all id_p  $availble > 1 then save(); into database

Comment: In the loop you did nothing !! you check the same count !!

Comment: What is the out put of  `dd($request->get('id_p'));` ?

Comment: @Maraboc if i add 2 product my  dd($request->get('id_p'))  = array:2[0 =>'13'   1=>'14']

Comment: @Maraboc i updated my code i try to put $availible id_p id_w  in my for loop i want to check every id_p before it save but it still check only 1st data

Comment: @Maraboc sir its work lol i used echo instead of return  echo thanks , now im working on loopingall data before save

Comment: You must check `$available = $this->check_stock($id_w, $id_p, $qty);` after initializations `$id_w = $request->input('idw');
     $id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];` !

Comment: @Maraboc its work now thanks